# How do I get my Broadcom BCM4313 working correctly?

Tags: wireless, kernel, drivers, broadcom, eeepc

I've installed ubuntu on a Asus 1015 netbook. Everything worked out of the box except for the Wireless adapter, which i had to install with the Additional Drivers application.

It apparently installed fine and connects to our wireless network, but it only works at a *"funny"* speed range that goes from 367Bytes to a peak of 3Kb in its best moments. I know for sure the problem is neither the network nor the hardware. Network speeds are normal under windows on this laptop and in other computers with ubuntu aswell.

lspci says the card is a BCM4313 model, but the Addittional Drivers Manager says

`these packecege contains Broadcom  802.11 Linux STA wireless driverfor use with Broadcom's BCM4311-, BCM4312-, BCM4321-, and BCM4322 based hardware`

seems like it installed the wrong driver... Is there anything I can do? I'm not concerned about compiling the driver or stuff like that, but I'm not sure on where to start... any help or guidance will be very, very appreciated.