# Wireless iwconfig rate auto too low

Tags: wireless, broadcom

left to its own devices my wireless connects at too low a speed. I have a 20meg internet connection and my wireless is slowing it down to like 3meg. When I reboot into windows it's fine. When I run `iwconfig eth1 rate 24M` or even `48M` the connection is much faster and runs fine, why won't it automatically go higher? Is this the fault of the driver? I am running Broadcom's driver compiled from source. Would adding `iwconfig eth1 rate 24M` to rc.local be the right way to force it at boot?

Output from iwconfig when rate=auto:

```
eth1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"honeypot"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.417 GHz  Access Point: xxx   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power:24 dBm   
          Retry min limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=5/5  Signal level=-47 dBm  Noise level=-91 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:2  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

Thanks, Jamie

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/12355/3940. What chipset is your wireless card?

Comment: I've already compiled and am using the drivers from source, so presumably his solution won't work for me, though I could try the binary drivers, I can't remember why I stopped using them. According to google the chipset is BCM4313, I don't have the machine in front of me atm.

Comment: Also that guy's speed is *very* low, max 3k, my wireless is connecting at 1meg minimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found a bug report:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wireless-tools/+bug/384920