# Problems with Broadcom 4313 on 64-bit Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: 64-bit, broadcom

As the title says, I have issues with my wireless connection. Almost every time I boot my laptop (a Dell Inspiron N3010), the wireless doesn't work. I need to plug in my network cable and reboot the computer for the wireless to start functioning.

Output of `lspci -nn | grep Wireless`:

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
```

Output of `lshw -C network`:

```
*-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: eth1
   version: 01
   serial: 68:a3:c4:10:7d:d7
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=5.100.82.38 ip=192.168.2.104 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:17 memory:f0300000-f0303fff
```

I looked at the solution given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12355/broadcom-bcm4313-working-but-terribly-slow/67806#67806), but I don't understand how I can install the recommended driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to uninstall the recommended driver...go to additional driver and deactivate it...

by the way give this a try:
http://www.computerandyou.net/2011/05/how-to-solve-no-wireless-networks-in-ubuntu-11-04/

Comment: abhishek, I installed the drivers, as suggested in the first solution, rebooted by computer, but the wireless still didn't work.

Comment: Hey Lucian...could you try the alternate solution 1 or 2 ...and see if that works....and just to be sure ..could you please post the output of sudo rfkill list all

Comment: I'm going to choose your answer as correct, because the wireless has been working for the last weeks. It stopped working for a while, when I upgraded the STA driver to the latest version, but after I downgraded, it started working again. Thanks.