# Unable to create/connect to wireless on a Dell n4050 with a BCM4313

Tags: 11.10, wireless, dell, broadcom, inspiron

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get my Broadcom BCM4313 working correctly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12355/how-do-i-get-my-broadcom-bcm4313-working-correctly)

I am new to ubuntu.I have already updated after fresh installation of 11.10.
It can detect wireless, but cannot **establish connections**.I am using Dell inspiron n4050.

BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller

Comment: See if this helps: http://askubuntu.com/questions/12355/broadcom-bcm4313-working-but-terribly-slow