# BCM4313 wireless card keeps disconnecting

Tags: 11.10, wireless, broadcom

I am new to Ubuntu and I have just installed Ubuntu 11.10.
The problem is that the BCM4313 wireless card keeps disconnecting all the time.

From the Additional drivers window, I can see that the "Broadcom STA wireless driver" is installed.

I would appreciate any help at the moment as I am thinking to return back to Windows.

The output of "lsmod | grep cfg80211" is 
cfg80211              199630  2 brcmsmac,mac80211

Comment: Could you paste the output of `lsmod | grep cfg80211` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Broadcom BCM4313 working, but terribly slow](http://askubuntu.com/questions/12355/broadcom-bcm4313-working-but-terribly-slow)

Comment: cfg80211              199630  2 brcmsmac,mac80211

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two drivers for this chip AFAIK.

Try `lsmod | grep cfg80211` and see if it outputs `wl` or `brcmsmac`.

[**brcmsmac**](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/brcm80211)

This is open-source driver which comes in the kernel so it should work out of the box. But in some case you may need to blacklist `bcma` module first. If you are not using it by default in order to give it a try do

```
sudo modprobe -r wl && sudo modprobe brcmsmac
```

OR if the above command doesnot give you anything

```
sudo modprobe -r bcma ssb wl && sudo modprobe brcmsmac
```

[**wl**](http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php)

This is the additional driver you are talking about provided by the package `broadcom-sta-common`. You can test it the same way as above just do.

`sudo modprobe -r brcmsmac bcma b43 && sudo modprobe wl`

The opensourcedriver doesnot have a LED support so your wireless LED won't turn on. Apart from that the open source driver doesnot have powersave option as well which is enabled during battery laptop usage. But my internet connection lagged during powersave option of `wl` driver.

If you find your internet connection lagging during battery try [How can I prevent iwconfig power management from being turned on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85214/how-can-i-prevent-iwconfig-power-management-from-being-turned-on/85223#85223)

See which works for you.

In order to make things permanent just add

`blacklist MODULE_NAME` in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and inorder to load the module add it in `/etc/modules`. So if you would like to  use say `wl` you would add

```
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma
blacklist ssb
blacklist b43
```

in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and add `wl` in `/etc/modules`

[This](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Broadcom_wireless) is a pretty good documentation on broadcom drivers.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but after trying both commands for brcmsmac still nothing happens :(

Comment: Did you try `wl` one as well ? Try permanent solutions.

Comment: No i just tried the brcmsmac because the output of "lsmod | grep cfg80211" is brcmsmac.

Comment: Should i try the wl ?

Comment: Well the output says what driver you are using, and your are using opensource driver by default not additional driver. If one doesnot solve your problem you should certainly try the next.