# How to enable 801.11 n with BCM4313

Tags: 11.10, wireless

I own a ASUS 1215N with the BCM4313 wireless radio.
In windows I can connect to "n" wireless networks without problem however Ubuntu 11.10 can only "see"  and connect to "g" networks.

I have already read through [How do I get my Broadcom BCM4313 working correctly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12355/how-do-i-get-my-broadcom-bcm4313-working-correctly) and [How do I get the Broadcom BCM4313 wireless working on an Asus 1015PX?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94021/how-do-i-get-the-broadcom-bcm4313-wireless-working-on-an-asus-1015px). According to them i run the correct drivers and i have blacklisted everything useless.
now this link http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1892229
says the 11.10 drivers have a bug and the OP solves this by compling himself a new driver, but how?

Answer (score 0):

Weather this solves the problem or not I dont know, but you compile the drivers by downloading [them](http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php)

uncompress and run

```
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Thanks, sadly it still doesnt work. Can see all the g networks from the neighbours yet my fathers n is not available,