# How to get brcmsac wireless drivers working?

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get my Broadcom BCM4313 working correctly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12355/how-do-i-get-my-broadcom-bcm4313-working-correctly)

i just installed ubuntu 12.04 on my HP Pavilion dv6 series laptop, and i am trying to get the included broadcom 4313 wireless chipset to work on monitor mode, i googled and found out that monitor mode is not supported with the default sta broadcom drivers, and many users recommended using the brcmsmac drivers which i understand are included in this version of ubuntu, the question is:

How do i properly purge/blacklist/delete the STA broadcom drivers so they don't cause problems with the brcmsmac?, and how do i set the brcmsmac driver to work properly?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to remove the proprietary STA driver is to make sure that the packages **broadcom-sta-common**, **broadcom-sta-source** and **bcmwl-kernel-source** are removed from the system. Do this with the Software Center or apt-get.

The brcmsmac (sometimes called brcm80211) driver is indeed part of the Linux kernel and included in Ubuntu along with firmware, so you should be set to go.