# Can't connect to wifi nor detect connections

Tags: wireless, internet

I had an issue with my laptop in which whenever  used Ubuntu connected to wifi, every other device on the same connection would slow to an unusable place. I researched and found [someone else had this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346804/one-ubuntu-laptop-on-wifi-occasionally-makes-other-laptops-connection-slow), and the solution there was to run the following:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'blacklist wl' >> /etc/modprobe.d/broadcomm-blacklist.conf
sudo sh -c "echo 'brcmsmac' >> /etc/modprobe.d/broadcomm.conf
```

Being dumb, I did that without fully understanding the consequences/what I was doing, and now my laptop cannot detect wifi connections at all. I suppose I have disabled my driver, though I have no idea how to get it working again.

After the fact, I noticed someone in the comments of the post I mention above warns against this very thing happening --> my fault! Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've added `blacklist wl` to `/etc/modprobe.d/broadcomm-blacklist.conf` and `brcmsmac` to `/etc/modprobe.d/broadcomm.conf`.

To revert your changes, just remove the lines you've added from the files using `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/broadcomm-blacklist.conf` and `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/broadcomm.conf`.

`sudo nano` will open a text editor (`nano`) as `su` (superuser/admin). Remove the lines you've added (navigate using your cursor keys), and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>enter</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>enter</kbd> again to save.

Also, are you sure it's "broadcomm" and not "broadcom"?

Comment: Thank you! Broadcom is the name of the driver, though "broadcomm" was what the script I'd used said, so that's what I had typed. Anyway, it's working now.