# " BCM4313 wireless card not detected unless I boot with an ethernet connection "

Tags: 12.04, wireless, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get my Broadcom BCM4313 working correctly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12355/how-do-i-get-my-broadcom-bcm4313-working-correctly)

*My Ubuntu 12.04 LTS does not detect any wireless network unless I reboot with the ethernet connected. With ethernet connection, both the WiFi and ethernet are detected and, even if I remove the cable, WiFi keeps working. However, each time, I am having to boot my laptop with the LAN connected to be able to use WLAN.

Here is my [hardware configuration](http://pastebin.com/J3KxjWvw*).
Well I posted this post about a day ago and today , I just uninstalled all the broadcom drivers etc ... and there without any drivers installed the wireless runs perfectly !!!

What's that all about?