# Ubuntu 12.10 64bit fresh install, wireless issue!

Tags: wireless, network-manager, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get my Broadcom BCM4313 working correctly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12355/how-do-i-get-my-broadcom-bcm4313-working-correctly)

Just installed a fresh Ubuntu 12.10 64bit on my laptop, run the update manager, restarted and suddenly I can't use my wifi anymore.

Ubuntu software center installed automatically the wifi additional driver as you can see in my screenshot.

[image: Additional drivers and wifi issue]

If I mark the option "Do not use the device" and apply changes, restarting Ubuntu my wifi is back and I can use it.

If I run `iwconfig` my terminal is showing this [image: iwconfig]

Now if I use Ubuntu for more than 20 minutes surfing the web my wifi it keeps to be connected but I don't receive any signal from it. Any page I try to open it simply don't open (just waiting icon). If I disconnect my wifi and connect it again, same issue, it doesn't work. The only way to make it work again is to restart Ubuntu. And the same story it happens again after   aprox. 20, 30 minutes.

**WIFI device details**: `03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4727] (rev 01)`

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: Please add your device details from the terminal command lspci -nn.

Comment: Added the device details!

Answer (score 3):

@chili555

I run this one using wired:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

and after a restart the wifi additional driver is actived and working
[image]

If my wifi will disconnect again I'll let you know.

Comment: Thank you Dave.. this got my Aspire 5750 (Ubuntu 12.10 64bit)´s wifi up and running again :) I did not even have to restart!!

Comment: if there's no option to connect via LAN, you can reboot using the previous kernel, wifi will work

Answer (score 0):

When you start and your wireless is not working, check to see if the correct module is loaded:

```
    lsmod | grep wl
```

If it is not listed, load it:

```
    sudo modprobe wl
```

Does your wireless spring to life? If so, let's get it to load automagically:

```
    sudo su
    echo wl >> /etc/modules
    exit
```

Now does your wireless start as expected on boot?