# Wifi is fine on Ubuntu but very slow on window 7

Tags: 13.04, wireless

this is the first time i come here, so sorry if i make some mistakes.

My question is: when my computer(Ubuntu 13.04) connect to wifi router, other computer(install window 7) will have slow connection but my computer is fine.

I try to config(router) to 11b 11g ... but nothing change.

Thank for your help!

**EDIT:** The result when i execute command `sudo lspci`  :

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev b5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Whistler [Radeon HD 6600M/6700M/7600M Series]
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)
03:00.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 04)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
```

Comment: I have the same issue with one of my Ubuntu machines... I thought it was my imagination, but apparently it is not! I'm not sure if this is a software or firmware problem... Can you boot that computer with windows and check if it still happens? Also, please paste the result of this command: sudo lspci

Comment: @HugoVieira I have updated my question :-)

Comment: So, your problem is on Windows... how is this an Ubuntu question?

Comment: @ThomasW. When my computer run with Window 7, other computer(same network with me) have no problem(wifi is fast). But everytime my computer run with Ubuntu 13.04, other computer will have slow wifi. So i think problem is on Ubuntu!

Comment: I don't think so, I think this is an unrelated issue related to your network itself, either your router or modem or some other component that is being allocated more priority than your other system, I'm pretty certain Ubuntu can't force your router to do that, so it's not an Ubuntu specific issue, more rather an issue with your network.

Comment: @ThomasW. When the problem occured, i thought the problem come from my router, but i have tried many configurations and reset for router but problem still occured :|

Comment: @Thomas, I have to disagree with you. I have this problem and all computers are running Ubuntu. It happens with two different routers (Asus and Thomson). It does not happen when the faulty computer is running Windows. It might not be an Ubuntu specific issue, but it sure is a Linux/Broadcom Drivers specific issue.

Comment: @RongNK I have the exact same wireless card that you have. It's an ASUS eeepc 1015PEM with a Broadcom 4313. It looks like an issue with the drivers for this wireless card. I'm no expert in wifi radio, so can't really understand how and why this is happening. If you are ok with experimenting, take a look at this thread: http://askubuntu.com/questions/12355/how-do-i-get-my-broadcom-bcm4313-working-correctly

Comment: @HugoVieira Many thanks to you, please post as answer :-)

Comment: @ThomasW. The problem is driver, now when i install exactly driver, my network work fine :-)

Comment: @RongNK What driver did you install, now?

Comment: @mniess I have used `jockey Addtional Drivers` to get driver. Now, i disabled that driver and reinstall default driver and then i set `modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac` and `modprobe brcmsmac`. And now, my network is fine :-)

Comment: This is a bug of certain modules of the Broadcomm devices, the "workaround" is using the old module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the exact same wireless card that you have. It's an ASUS eeepc 1015PEM with a Broadcom 4313. It looks like an issue with the drivers for this wireless card. I'm no expert in wifi radio, so can't really understand how and why this is happening.

If you are ok with experimenting, take a look at this thread: [How do I get my Broadcom BCM4313 working correctly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12355/how-do-i-get-my-broadcom-bcm4313-working-correctly)