# WiFi configuration problem?

Tags: 13.04, wireless

I created a question before:
[Wifi is fine on Ubuntu but very slow on window 7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/355654/wifi-is-fine-on-ubuntu-but-very-slow-on-window-7)

And I found a solution by running this command: 
`sudo modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac wl || sudo modprobe brcmsmac`

But everytime I restart my computer, I must run it again. If not, other computer in my network will have slow connection. And my questions are:

**1.** Why `wl` mode is the reason?

**2.** How to set permanently this configuration?

Thank for your attention :-)

Comment: This may help you to how to fix it after each and every restart
[See here][1]

 


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/127757/how-do-i-make-modprobe-changes-permanent

Comment: What do you mean by *"Why wl mode is the reason?"*? `wl` is the kernel module name of Broadcom's proprietary driver. You indicate a whole bunch of modules to be unloaded before it works with the `brcmsmac` kernel module. So I don't understand your question specifically to `wl`.

Comment: @gertvdijk If i set `sudo modprobe wl`, others computers in my network will have slow internet connection :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu 13.04, I believe the default bcmwl-kernel-source will not work correctly for your Broadcom 4313. I recommend that you get a temporary wired ethernet connection and open a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_5.100.82.112+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
```

Or, if yours is a 32-bit system:

```
wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_5.100.82.112+bdcom-0ubuntu3_i386.deb
```

Confirm 32- or 64-bit:

```
arch
```

Then do:

```
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl*.deb
```

Reboot and give us your report.

Comment: Thank you. if you can explain how this driver cause slowing down the entire network, i alway appreciate :-)

Comment: I wish I could give you a good answer. I only know the usual solution.

Answer (score 1):

Blacklist the kernel modules you don't want to load in the first place by putting them in a file in `/etc/modprobe.d/` like this:

1. Create the file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-mywireless.conf`

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-mywireless.conf
   ```
2. For *each* module you don't want to load at bootup, put on a single line: `blacklist modulename`, e.g.:

   ```
   blacklist b44
   blacklist b43
   blacklist b43legacy
   blacklist ssb
   blacklist wl
   ```
3. Save and close the file.
4. Add a line to `/etc/modules` for each module you *do* want to load, e.g.:

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/modules
   ```

   Append, on a new line:

   ```
   brcmsmac
   ```
5. Save and close.
6. Reboot.

Comment: Please run the terminal command: lspdi -nn -d 14e4:  Is your wireless device 14e4:4727? The most recent driver wl has an issue with slowing down the entire network. Please confirm and I'll post the fix.

Comment: @chili555 You're right, my wireless device is 14e4:4727 :-)