# I can't connect to the internet through wi-fi

Tags: 13.04, wireless, updates, 13.10

I can't connect to the internet through wi-fi, when I try to connect it sends a message: "network disconnected" (update my version of ubuntu from 13.04 to 13.10 through wired connection)

Comment: It is safe to run it was written by me and some good friends it will help diagnose your wireless issue.
Paste this command in a terminal  `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` 
It will download a script and create a file named (wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz) in your home folder paste the contents of the file here http://pastebin.com/ then paste the link back here.  No internet then go to this link for running the script without internet.
[url]http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12350385[/url]

Comment: Did you try the answer on this page? http://askubuntu.com/questions/360478/wifi-problems-after-upgrading-to-13-10