# Can't access websites but connected to wifi

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.10, internet

Since I've upgraded from 12.10 to 13.10 I cannot access any websites on any browser but I can use the Ubuntu Software Center. I am a complete noob when it comes to ubuntu and any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

PS: I am using a MacBook 3.1

Comment: Are you behind proxy?

Comment: No, I am not behind a proxy.

Comment: Did you try `ping askubuntu.com`?

Comment: @landroni I did, the result was "ping: unknown host askubuntu.com" I am currently using a friends computer to post this.

Comment: What does it show you on network icon in upper right corner?

Comment: Did you try the answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/360478/wifi-problems-after-upgrading-to-13-10