# Wifi is connected but internet can't be accessed

Tags: wireless, networking, internet

I have a HP 110-mini laptop dual booting Ubuntu 13.10 and Windows 7. I am trying to build LFS. But recently, my internet access just went off. It says I am connected to the wifi and I can access the internet with other devices, I can also access internet on the same laptop when I am booted into windows 7. Only when am on UBuntu every browser says server can't be found.
Can you please help me?

Comment: please provide result of "ifconfig" and "sudo lshw -C network"

Comment: also please provide result of `nm-tool`

Comment: Did you try the answer on this page? http://askubuntu.com/questions/360478/wifi-problems-after-upgrading-to-13-10

Comment: try dropping in *sudo dhclient wlan0* and follow it with *ping -c 3 www.google.com*.. If that works, you need to go into network settings (click on the cog in the top right>system settings>Network>wireless>click on the orange arrow associated to your network>settings>ipv4/ipv6 settings and turn on dhcp.

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe it is a proxy related problem.** 
When I shutdown OS with proxy software on, I can't access the Internet the next time when boot into this OS. 
**In this case, open proxy software again may solve the problem.**