# Unstable wi-fi connection

Tags: wireless

My pc has had connection problems ever since I installed Ubuntu... The cable connection got better and solved, however the wi-fi one... Windows in this pc caught wi-fi nicely, and another Ubuntu pc also catches strong signal, along with android devices, so something got to be up with mine.

A̶n̶d̶ ̶h̶e̶r̶e̶'̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶"̶b̶i̶g̶g̶e̶r̶ ̶p̶i̶c̶"̶:
h̶t̶t̶p̶:̶/̶/̶p̶a̶s̶t̶e̶b̶i̶n̶.̶c̶o̶m̶/̶2̶s̶J̶g̶U̶T̶n̶q (not anymore, it got deleted)

> *-network
>
> ```
>   description: Wireless interface
>   product: RTL8191SEvB Wireless LAN Controller
>   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
>   logical name: wlan0
>   version: 10
>   width: 32 bits
>   clock: 33MHz
>   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
>   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192se driverversion=3.11.0-26-generic 
>   firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
>   resources: irq:17 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d4000000-d4003fff
> ```

I've tried this:
[Don't have network connection using a BCM4313 adapter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360478/dont-have-network-connection-using-a-bcm4313-adapter)

> sudo modprobe -rv wl
>
> sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
>
> sudo modprobe -v brcmsmac

But it's the same, if not a bit worse. Additional controllers has only my graphics card one, and I'm half scared that trying something else might strip me of what little I have left (and I'm not sure when I'll get cable connection), so ask for help instead.

Comment: Workaround : It's possible to go around this if the computer is connected to power (otherwise battery will die out quickly). Have a android device connected to wi-fi, linked by USB set to media link and then USB tethering (under more in wireless & networks settings). Now connection is smooth and fast... Not a solution, but better than nothing. Though I'd post this in case anyone would like to know (I've just figured it out myself).